# How to disable grid dots in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

The visual preview of the form's background is dotted.

[image]

This is making it hard for me to do visual editing and is confusing me while making my custom GUI's. I've tried the following:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why have you deleted [tag:visual-studio-customization], @JJJ? Why is it bad to have separate tag for questions about VS configuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a WinForm designer option.  It is controlled by the `DrawGrid` property shown in the `PropertyGrid` for a `Form`.  Set the property to false to disable the grid.

There is a complimentary property named `GridSize` that is used to set the grid spacing.  Another related property is the `SnapToGrid` property that controls whether placed/moved controls snap to the shown grid.

Comment: I can not remember the last time that I saw `DrawGrid` property, maybe Visual Studio 2003?

Comment: Am I missing something? :\

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I thought your 1st comment related to the introduction of the snapline designer mode in VS2005.  If you are claiming that DrawGrid designer property does not exist, then that is false.  The property is hidden if using the layout mode=Snaplines, but is generated by the ParentControl designer when the layout mode is set = SnapToGrid.  You need to close/reopen the designer to see the changes.  use the categorized property view and see the `Design` category.

Comment: Great! So that's why the last time that I've seen them was VS2003 era! After that I always use SnapLines! Thanks for the information! Anyway just for the OP to know, those properties in design mode of the form override the global options.

Answer (score 1):

To disable showing grid in design mode:

1. Go to *Tools* → *Options*
2. In the options categories in *Options* window, go to *Windows Forms Designer* → *General*
3. In property grid, expand the *Layout Setting* group. You can do either of these options:

   - Set *Layout Mode* to *SnapLines*.
   - Or set *Layout Mode* to *SnapToGrid* and *Show Grid* to *False*
4. Press *OK* to close the *Options* window.
5. Close the designer window and re-open it.

Comment: I believe i have tried something like this before and one of the options were missing from the options menu. I will double check this